# I donated cryptocurrency to a charity, but the receipt is in dollars. How is it taxed?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, cryptocurrency, donation

In 2022 I made a donation of $100 to a tax-exempt charity, which I paid using cryptocurrency (let's say 123.456 units of currency XYZ).  The tax receipt I got from the charity acknowledges a donation of $100 but says nothing at all about cryptocurrency, probably because their payment processor (BitPay) converted it transparently.

For purposes of US income tax, I am not sure if this was:

1. a contribution of property, namely the 123.456 XYZ, or
2. a sale of 123.456 XYZ for $100, followed by a cash contribution of $100.

In case 1, in order to claim a deduction on Form 1040 Schedule A (yes, I am itemizing), IRS Pub 526 says I am supposed to have a receipt that includes:

> A description of the
> property in sufficient detail under the circumstances (taking into
> account the value of the property) for a person not generally
> familiar with the type of property to understand that the
> description is of the contributed property.

Well, my receipt doesn't have that.  There is an exception when it is "impractical to get a receipt", in which case I would be allowed to substitute my own written records, but I am not sure if that applies here.

In case 2, I suppose I would report the sale on Form 8949, thus paying capital gains tax, and then claim the $100 deduction on Schedule A as above.

Which is correct?

Comment: Is this specific to crypto? What if you donate or buy something in currency X but it's sold in currency Y ?

Comment: Well, cryptocurrency is considered under US tax law to be "property" and not currency.  It would probably be the same if I had donated a lump of silver, but I don't know about foreign currency.  There is a key difference between "donate" and "buy": donations are tax deductible, but only if specific documentation ("substantiation") requirements are met.

Answer (score 1):

You are taxed on the value of the donation. If the receipt gives a value in dollars, that's what you use unless you want to try to show that they misvalued it somehow (the IRS is going to be very skeptical...).

If they ***didn't*** give a value, it's your responsibility to figure out what the value was at the time of donation. For stock shares, that's easy; closing price on that day. For physical objects you need to have some reference to establish the value; checking what equivalent objects in equivalent condition have recently successfully sold for on eBay has become a commonly used shortcut for that. I have no idea what the best practice would be for cryptocurrency but I would hope it's more like the former than the latter.

Comment: Sure, either way, the amount of the deduction will be $100.  It's a popular currency with an active market, so there should be plenty of evidence that $100 was the correct value.  My question is (a) do I have enough documentation to meet the IRS substantiation requirement, and (b) do I need to report a capital gain?

Comment: (a) yes. (b) No clue.

Comment: @NateEldredge yes, you need to report the disposition. You contributed dollars, not XYZ, because that's what the charity acknowledged, so the disposition is your responsibility and you need to report your gain from the sale of 123.456 XYZ.

Comment: With most securities, if you donate the security to a tax exempt organization, the capital gains are technically theirs but since they're exempt they don't get taxed on them. (This is why it's preferable to donate the security, if the org can handle that, rather than cashing it out and donating the money; effectively it costs you less per amount donated.) I have no least clue whether cryptocurrency gains would be handled the same way. Maybe the org you donated to can answer that.

Comment: @keshlam there's no reason they couldn't be, but in this case the org didn't get crypto - it got dollars. The OP essentially paid with XYZ just as they would pay with a credit card, but the processor in this case converted XYZ into USD, which is a taxable disposition.

Comment: It that was done by the processor, agreed. If the charity accepted the crypto but acknowledged it in dollars -- as happens when donating stock shares -- I'm honestly not certain; I would _think_ it would be defendable as an in-kind donation but law doesn't always do the obvious. And there are probably a few charities which do accept some cryptocurrencies directly. (I recently set up a DAF, which since it's a charity itself can be funded with securities to get the tax advantage and then write checks to organizations so they don't need to handle accepting and converting the shares.)

Comment: @littleadv I'm trying to better understand your argument here. Are you arguing that it matters whether the charity keeps an asset for some amount of time or immediately sells it? The OP didn't open the payment processing account - imo it's clear that the charity initiated the sale of the cryptocurrency, not him. It seems to me that this situation is the same as if the charity accepted a share of stock to a broker that was instructed to automatically sell all stock upon receiving it. In respect to tax laws, I believe it's irrelevant what the charity "acknowledges" or prints out on the receipt.

Comment: I think we're agreeing that there should be no capital gains or losses on this transaction. The value that the charity receives is what can be claimed as a donation, again just as if I gave them shares that they immediately sold, and that value is what's substantiated by the receipt.

Comment: ```imo it's clear that the charity initiated the sale of the cryptocurrency``` - what are you basing this on? The charity provided an acknowledgment that they *received* $100. The OP also acknowledged that they *donated* $100. The XYZ is a red herring, and is irrelevant to the donation.

Comment: ```In respect to tax laws, I believe it's irrelevant what the charity "acknowledges" or prints out on the receipt``` - no, it is very much relevant. The claim of transfer of asset needs to be substantiated and in the scenario described here there's absolutely nothing the OP can show that they intended to transfer XYZ, and that the charity in fact received XYZ. In the question the OP clearly states that they intended to donate $100.

Comment: @keshlam that is true, but not exactly. Limits on transfer of assets and transfer of cash are different, but more importantly - the OP is asking about capital gains tax which should still be paid, and so is potentially NIIT and the additional medicare, depending on the situation. It is unclear if the OP is itemizing the deductions and can reduce the income by the value of the donation, but while with transfer of assets it wouldn't matter - with transfer of cash it does. So yes, there's a problem here for the OP.

Comment: The question is whether crypto is cash. I don't think it is, in the US, but gods only know what the latest case law is. If it's donation in kind, the charity would pay the capital gains tax when it is sold -- or not, if they're exempt. My share donations are in-kind, get a receipt for the value as sold, and I use that as the deductible value; I would hope crypto in-kind would be treated the same way, but I suspect this is still in the "if we wave our hands fast enough, can we fly" phase of tax law.

Comment: Note that if I donate what I think is $100 of shares but the charity can only sell it for $90, my deductible is $90. On the other hand if they sell it for $110 my deductible is $110. This is not (if you have a receipt that states the value, which I _thought_ was given?) a case where I donate an object and have to document value by providing references for its value at time of donation because the charity can't estimate or track what it will eventually sell for. (Darned touch kbd...)

Comment: @littleadv: Yes, I am itemizing deductions, and I would like to be able to deduct the value of the donation, one way or the other.  (I included that in the question.)